# Read big images in java

Tags: java, javafx, io

I'm developping a simple image organizer in java to sort quickly hundred of photos taken with my camera. The program has a list of photos(file paths) and displays a given photo

When I want to display one of them, it takes more than a second to load the file (~ 10Mb).
In this case, the sorting isn't efficient.

```
FXML private ImageView preview;

....

private void showMedia(Media m) {
    if(m != null) {
        Image i = new Image(new File(m.getPath()).toURI().toString());
        m.loadMediaProperties();
        this.preview.setImage(i);
    }
    else
        this.preview.setImage(null);
}
```

The constructor of Image class consumes time to loading the given file. I tried to keep the instance of Image for each Media but it I get "java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space"
I'm looking for a way to load and display a photo almost instantaneous (like adobe lightroom if you know).

Comment: *it takes more than a second to load the file (~ 10Mb)*  What's your storage hardware?  5400 RPM SATA drives are s-l-o-w.

Comment: @trashgod I think this is a JavaFX question...

Comment: There are two distinct parts to your question. For the time to load, consider background-loading the image, which you can do "out of the box" with one of the [`Image` constructors](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/image/Image.html#Image-java.lang.String-boolean-) taking a background-loading flag. For memory consumption, if you want to display the image full-size, there's little you can do, but if you just want thumbnails, you can specify the required size on load, which will reduce memory consumption.

Comment: @trashgod Well, yes, you could do that, but JavaFX `Image` has background loading baked in. See, e.g. [this constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/image/Image.html#Image-java.lang.String-boolean-) (and others).

Comment: @AndrewHenle Yeah, my storage hardware sucks ... I will test my program on another computer !

Answer (score 0):

Your goal cannot be achieved by such a simple, brute force approach as you are trying and Adobe Lightroom also does not work that way. Lightroom maintains a database of thumbnails and preview images and uses a lot of caching in order to give you a good performance and you would have to do the same in your application if you want to achieve a similar result. Utitizing background loading and processing is also key to a good performance here.

Comment: I applied your advices, I reduced the loading with background loading and  the expected dimensions of the image.
I will see with mates if the result is comfortable to sort!